# SQL: как сделать выборку по паре уникальных значений?

Tags: sql, join

У меня есть таблица `logs`, в ней есть, скажем, следующие поля;

```
user_IP     varchar(128)
fingerprint varchar(255)
```

Мне необходимо осуществить группировку по паре `"user_IP" + "fingerprint"`, то есть, вывести все уникальные пары `"user_IP" + "fingerprint"`, а также, указать количество сгруппированных строк (совпадений по конкретной паре).

Пример вывода:

```
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+
| user_IP     | fingerprint    | count (совпадений) |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+
| 10.20.30.40 | 0c013cb7e36bbe |                322 |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+
| 20.30.40.50 | 9f051f4a62bf7a |                  4 |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+
```

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: *Мне необходимо осуществить группировку по паре "user_IP" + "fingerprint"* Осуществляйте, что мешает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то достаточно просто в **GROUP BY** добавить столбцы, по которым хотите группировать и в **SELECT** счетчик по одному из столбцов. 
У вас это будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT user_IP, fingerprint, COUNT(user_IP) FROM logs GROUP BY user_IP, fingerprint;
```